# Windows service is not finding the connection string for an external library

Tags: c#, entity-framework, windows-services

First time doing a windows service, but what I have is very simple. 1 app I am using elsewhere for logging and then the service app that I want to log start and stops of the service.

The logging app is EF if that matters.

The connection string is in the app.config (in the service app and the logging app) just like I have in other places I am using the logging app. When the service is compiled it is located in the service.exe.config file.

Yet when the service tries to install, I get the error that the connection string cannot be found.

Is there something different I have to do when it's a windows service?

Thanx ahead of time.

Comment: Due to this being entity-framework do you have your connection string named the same as your context?  That trips me up all the time.

Comment: Never heard that, but I double checked any yes they are both the same. Currently "LoggingEntities" is the name of the context and the connection string.

Comment: "when the service tries to install". Is the service installing itself or is there another application that is trying to connect.

Comment: Sorry new at a service projects, but I am just running InstallUtil Service.exe. Hope that answers the question. I first tested before having the logging project as part of the service and that worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input. Guess I just had a bad project. Started a brand new project, same code and everything and it works fine now.

Had that happen once before with an MVC project, 3 months of development in and all the sudden nothing worked. Had to create a new project and copy all the same code over and worked fine. Think that one was vs 2013 also, but can't remember.

Thanx